# Generate images from a grayscale trained GAN pkl file

Tags: python, python-imaging-library, stylegan

I have trained a stylegan using a set of grayscale images, now I am stuck in the generate.py because it is all set for generating RGB images.
I get this error:

```
ValueError: not enough image data
```

when I changed the generate.py archive from stylegan pytorch from RGB to L :

```
ValueError: Too many dimensions: 3 > 2.
```

This is the whole generate.py code:
https://github.com/mit-han-lab/data-efficient-gans/blob/master/DiffAugment-stylegan2-pytorch/generate.py

I have searched the internet for hours and tried a lot of stuff but I am pretty new to python so I have run out of ideas of what I need to change in the generate.py to be able to have the images, can somebody please help me?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 1):

I ran into this problem a lot, too...

Finally found that it had something to do with indexing the img var.

Check lines 137-140 here: https://github.com/pgtinsley/stylegan3/blob/main/gen_images_gray.py

That's for StyleGAN3, but the code/logic should transfer over to SG2 pretty easily.

Best of luck!

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).